# The efficiency when implementing a dataframe using java: list of row VS. list of column?

Tags: java, list, dataframe, performance, arraylist

I'm going to write a piece of code that accepts a list of String, then splits each string into a list by delimiter (now there is a data frame). then I'm going to get a specific column as a list, performing some operation on it (like toUpperCase), then I would put it back. Finally I would repack the data frame into a list of String.

I had two plan for this:

**1.**

```
 public List<String> transform(List<String> events, String delimiter, int columnIndex) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<String[]> df = new LinkedList<>();
        List<String> oldCol = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String event: events) {
            String[] row = event.split(delimiter);
            df.add(row);
            oldCol.add(row[columnIndex]);
        }

        List<String> newCol = oldCol.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        for (String[] row: df) {
            row[columnIndex] = newCol.get(i++);
            String newRow =  String.join(delimiter, row);
            res.add(newRow);
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((endTime - startTime) + "ms");
        return res;
    }
```

**2.**

```
    public List<String> transform2(List<String> events, String delimiter, int width, int columnIndex) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<List<String>> df = new LinkedList<>();
            List<String> oldCol = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int a=0; a<width;a++){
                df.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            for(String event: events) {
                String[] row = event.split(delimiter);
                int len = df.isEmpty() ? 0 : df.get(0).size();
                for(int c = 0; c < df.size(); ++c) {
                    List<String> col = df.get(c);
                    col.add(null);
                    df.set(c, col);
                }
                for(int e = 0; e < df.size(); ++e) {
                    df.get(e).set(len, e < row.length ? row[e] : "");
                }
                oldCol.add(row[columnIndex]);
            }

          List<String> newCol = oldCol.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
          List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
          for(int i=0; i<df.get(0).size(); i++){
            df.get(columnIndex).set(i,newCol.get(i));
            StringBuilder rowString = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j=0; j<df.size()-1; j++){
                rowString.append(df.get(j).get(i));
                rowString.append(",");
            }
            rowString.append(df.get(df.size()-1).get(i));
            res.add(rowString.toString());
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((endTime - startTime) + "ms");
        return res;
}
```

I test these two plan with some cases (millions of String / hundreds of String / three columns / ten columns) as input. The performance of **No.2** is always better than **No.1**. However, I could not explain it very well.

Could anyone help me explain performance of these two plans, maybe from performance analysis of ArrayList and LinkedList, or ArrayList resizing, etc.

Comment: You can heavily improve performance. There is no need to store the column data separately. `List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(events.size());
for (String event : events) {
String[] row = event.split(delimiter);
row[columnIndex] = row[columnIndex].toUpperCase();
res.add(String.join(delimiter, row));
}` is all you need in your `transform` method. Creating a result list with the same size as the data going in should eliminate the need to copy the `ArrayList` when its size limit is crossed. Also, we only need to iterate over the data once to build the result

Comment: And if you need to apply different functions to different columns, then go with this: `public List<String> transform(List<String> events, String delimiter,Map<Integer, Function<String, String>> colFunctionMap) {List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(events.size());for (String event : events) {String[] row = event.split(delimiter);for (Entry<Integer, Function<String, String>> e : colFunctionMap.entrySet()) {row[e.getKey()] = e.getValue().apply(row[e.getKey()]);}res.add(String.join(delimiter, row));}return res;}`

Comment: Thanks XtremeBaumer. Thank you for your optimization.  Sorry for not making it clear. there is a context that I could only get the column as a List and pass the List to another host, and then I would get a list as the return value (for performance also)

Comment: I tried to construct the df as am empty ArrayList with specifying the initial capacity of the list as the size of List<String> events in Plan No.1, however, No.1 is still less efficient than No.2

Comment: The host can only work on a `List<String>`? Could probably be more performant, to map the data to POJO, and have the host update the field of the POJO

Comment: I did some more performance testing. The result on transforming 50.000 rows 500 times, was that your first method actually came out ahead. When testing performance, you can't just make a single pass for each method per JVM start. You need to make multiple to have the JVM "warm up" and have optimization kick in. Currently running a larger test (500k rows 5k times), but I expect the result to be similar. So after the JVM starts optimizing, your first method should be better